# What is the Project Type GUID for a Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

Instructions on how to locate:  http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx

(I do not have Windows 10 installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
```

Let me know if it does not work.